# Генераця ELF файлов

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, elf, opcode

K примеру у меня есть байтовый массив готовых опкодов. Как мне сгенерировать ELF файл вместе с этими опкодами? Есть ли какая-то готовая библиотека для этого на С?

Comment: Используйте libelf, libbfd, ну и так далее.

Answer (score 4):

Возможно не самый оптимальный вариант, но это то как бы делал я. Берем [flat assember](http://flatassembler.net), пишем для него следующий код:

Вариант для 32-битного ELF:

```
format ELF executable 3
entry start

segment readable executable

start:
    file 'opcodes.bin'
```

Для получения 64-битного ELF нужно в первой строке поменять ELF на ELF64.

`opcodes.bin` - имя файла с вашими опкодами (в бинарном виде, не шестнадцатеричном).

Собирается просто: `fasm имя_файла.asm`

Comment: А если допустим мне нужно задать секцию .data, то я так понимаю никак это не сделать кроме как руками? Просто я пишу мини компилятор где так же нужно будет генерировать не только .text, но и .data с .rodata

Comment: @Corle, если пишете компилятор - это уже другой вопрос. Лучше посмотреть исходники какого-то существующего компилятора, например gcc или tinyc. Если через fasm делать - можно генерировать программно исходник asm нужного вида, потом ассемблировать.